# How can I turn my PHP quiz into an HTML form quiz using foreach and arrays?

Tags: php, html, forms, foreach

I have been trying to translate the quiz I made in PHP into HTML using a text form. I have tried 2 different methods but I can't seem to get either one to work and I'm afraid I might be on the wrong path completely.
heres method 1:

```
<?php

$countries = [
    'Tokyo' => 'Japan',
    'Mexico-city' => 'Mexico',
    'Washington D.C.' => 'USA',
    'New Delhi' => 'India',
    'Seoul' => 'Zouth-Korea',
    'Peking' => 'China',
    'Abuja' => 'Nigeria',
    'Buenos Aires' => 'Argentina',
    'Cairo' => 'Egypt',
    'London' => 'England',
];
$answer = [];
$question = 'What is the capital city of Japan?';
$input = '';
$country = '';
$city = '';


?> 
<div class="pblock">
    <form action="topo.php" method="post" id="quiz-form">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="input" id="input" value="<?php $input; ?>" />
    </p>
    <br>
<?php
   foreach ($countries as $city => $country) { 

        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $input = $_POST["input"];
            $question = 'What is the capital city of ' . $country . '?';
            $countries[] = $input; 
            
            if ($input == $city) {
                $answer[] = $input;
                echo 'Correct!' . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                echo 'Incorrect, ' . $input . ' is not the capital city of ' . $country . '.' . PHP_EOL;
                echo 'The correct answer is: ' . $city . PHP_EOL;
            }break;  
        } 
    }
    $result = count($answer);
    echo $question;
?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="check" />
    </form>
</div>
```

```
and for method 2:
```

```
<?php

$countries = [
    'Tokyo' => 'Japan',
    'Mexico-city' => 'Mexico',
    'Washington D.C.' => 'USA',
    'New Delhi' => 'India',
    'Seoul' => 'Zouth-Korea',
    'Peking' => 'China',
    'Abuja' => 'Nigeria',
    'Buenos Aires' => 'Argentina',
    'Cairo' => 'Egypt',
    'London' => 'England',
];
$answer = [];
$input = '';
$country = '';
$city = '';

?>
    <form action="" method="post" id="quiz-form">
<?php

foreach ($countries as $city => $country) { 
    $question = 'What is the capital city of ' . $country . '?';
    ?>
    <div class="pblock">
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="input" id="input" value="<?php $input; ?>" />
            <?php echo $question ?>
        </p>
        <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="check" /> 
    </div>
    <?php

        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $input = $_POST["input"];
            $countries[] = $input; 
            
            if ($input == $city) {
                $answer[] = $input;
                echo 'Correct!' . PHP_EOL; 
            } else {
                echo 'Incorrect, ' . $input . ' is not the capital city of ' . $country . '.' . PHP_EOL;?><br><?php
                echo 'The correct answer is: ' . $city . '.' . PHP_EOL;?><br><?php
            }break;
        } 
    } 
    $result = count($answer);?>
</form>
```

I am aware that my code is probably completely off, but I have not been able to find another example for this method online.

I have tried to have my one div with text form appear, and have the quiz question change each time the submit button is clicked. however the loop does not work correctly, in which the question does not change properly.
I have tried to have all the questions in text forms on the same page with their own check button (to be honest I didn't really know what I had to do to get this one to work at all), but any check button being clicked, does not check the current question, and responds in a similar way as in method 1.

Comment: `name="input"` would need to be `name="input[]"` if you want to submit multiple responses with the same field name. When the form submits, `$_POST["input"]` would then be an array you can loop through. And putting the code which deals with the responses inside the loop which deals with rendering the questions makes no sense. You only need to process the responses once, when the form is submitted.

Comment: `value="<?php $input; ?>"` will not do anything, you'd need to output the value: `value="<?php echo $input; ?>"`